# How to reverse GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("Domain/User")?

Tags: powershell, newsfeed, mysite

In our SP2013 on-premise farm, we have two web applications. One for standard team sites and one for MySiteHost. These 2 web application are running under two different IIS app pool with two different identity.

Users followed some sites. The users can post newsfeed directly from their Mysite to those team site's newsfeed. However, they encountered error. After investigation, (refer to [this site](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/82/-There-was-a-problem-retrieving-the-latest-activity--Please-try-again-later)) I ran follow scripts:

```
$wa= Get-SPWebApplication $WebApp_MySite
$wa.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity($ID_WebApp)
$wa= Get-SPWebApplication $WebApp
$wa.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity($ID_WebApp_Mysite)
```

It seems fix the problem. However someone told me I don't need to run last 2 lines. It grants unncessary permission to users.

My question is, how can I reverse what I have done?

Answer (score 1):

In Central Administration, on page `/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx` select your WebApp and click on `User Policy` in ribbon. You can see in a dialogbox your account `ID_WebApp_MySite` with full control. Select it and click `Delete selected users`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I ran a few tests, I found GrantAccessToProcessIdentity command will grant the user to all content databases under that web application, too.

Comment: Hi using powershell how to remove these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a permission from the Web Application:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication $WebApp_MySite

$wa.policies.remove("Policy Name")
```